# Can I disable a dev-dependency feature for release mode?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Recently, I investigated my rust project build times using `cargo build --release --timings` and found out that a dev-dependency feature takes up a lot of build time despite being in release mode.

In particular, I use `sea-orm` with the following features, whereas the `sqlite` feature is only used for testing:

```ini
[dependencies.sea-orm]
version = "0.11"
features = ["runtime-tokio-rustls", "sqlx-mysql", "macros"]
default-features = false

[dev-dependencies]
sea-orm = { version = "0.11", features = ["sqlx-sqlite"]}
```

Naturally, cargo resolves all these features together in the `cargo.lock`. However, building the sqlite sys library takes up a big chunk of the build time, even in release mode.

While not critical, it would be nice to exclude this feature while building the release profile. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how the original feature resolver for Cargo works; feature flags are unified across everything.

Fortunately, there was a [feature resolver version 2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/features.html#feature-resolver-version-2) introduced in Rust 2021 that splits these up a bit more like you'd expect (separate "buckets" for build-dependencies, dev-dependencies, and platform specific flags) but at the potential cost of compiling some crates multiple times (if they have different feature flags enabled in different "buckets").

There's a few reasons why you might not be using the new feature resolver:

- If your crate uses `edition = "2018"` or earlier, it will use the original resolver by default. You can either update to `edition = "2021"` or specify `resolver = "2"` in your Cargo.toml's `[package]`.
- If you are using a workspace with a root package, it only uses what the root Cargo.toml is configured for, so if that uses a prior edition use the steps above.
- If you are using a workspace without a root package - members only (i.e. a virtual manifest) then it will use the original resolver by default. You will need to specify `resolver = "2"` in your `[workspace]`.

See also:

- [Cargo's New Feature Resolver](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/03/25/Rust-1.51.0.html#cargos-new-feature-resolver) in the Rust Blog.
- [Default Cargo feature resolver](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/default-cargo-resolver.html) in the Rust Edition Guide.

Comment: Ah! I remember reading about different resolver versions a while ago. I'm using the 2021 edition in my crates, however, I wasn't aware that the default for workspaces is still version 1.

Thanks, that does indeed work like a charm!

(Also the correct syntax is `resolver = "2"` for people stumbling over this in the future)

Comment: @Plebshot Thanks for the correction! I've edited. Not sure what I was thinking!